# How to implode array indexes?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

Is it possible to implode array's indexes? A function is returning me an array and what I need are the indexes of that array so I want to implode only inexes with comma or any other character for my db work

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You mean something like this...

```
implode(',', array_keys($some_arr));
```

... right? ) Here's [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) for `array_keys`; in short, when called with a single argument (an array), this function just returns all its keys (as array).

Comment: It's worth noting that this will work for either auto assigned indicies, or for those you assign yourself with square bracket notation.